# Stack plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've encountered a problem I cannot wrap my head around. I have data like

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- structure(list(time = c(14, 14, 20, 20, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 
27, 27, 27, 27, 29, 29, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 37, 37, 
38, 38, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 47, 47, 50, 50, 50, 50), name = c("x", 
"z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", 
"x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", 
"z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z"
), value = c(1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```r
|    |   time | name   |   value |
|---:|-------:|:-------|--------:|
|  0 |     20 | x      |       0 |
|  1 |     20 | z      |       1 |
|  2 |     23 | x      |       1 |
|  3 |     23 | z      |       1 |
|  4 |     24 | x      |       2 |
|  5 |     24 | z      |       1 |
|  6 |     28 | x      |       2 |
|  7 |     28 | z      |       1 |
|  8 |     29 | x      |       2 |
|  9 |     29 | z      |       1 |
| 10 |     31 | x      |       2 |
| 11 |     31 | z      |       2 |
| 12 |     31 | x      |       2 |
| 13 |     31 | z      |       2 |
| 14 |     32 | x      |       2 |
| 15 |     32 | z      |       2 |
| 16 |     33 | x      |       2 |
| 17 |     33 | z      |       3 |
| 18 |     33 | x      |       3 |
| 19 |     33 | z      |       3 |
| 20 |     34 | x      |       3 |
| 21 |     34 | z      |       3 |
| 22 |     34 | x      |       3 |
| 23 |     34 | z      |       3 |
| 24 |     34 | x      |       3 |
| 25 |     34 | z      |       3 |
| 26 |     36 | x      |       3 |
| 27 |     36 | z      |       3 |
| 28 |     37 | x      |       3 |
| 29 |     37 | z      |       3 |
| 30 |     40 | x      |       4 |
| 31 |     40 | z      |       3 |
| 32 |     41 | x      |       5 |
| 33 |     41 | z      |       3 |
| 34 |     44 | x      |       5 |
| 35 |     44 | z      |       3 |
| 36 |     45 | x      |       5 |
| 37 |     45 | z      |       3 |
| 38 |     51 | x      |       5 |
| 39 |     51 | z      |       3 |
```

Values by `name` are non decreasing in `time`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(time, value, group = name, color = name)) +
    geom_line()
```

[line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ps1j.png)

I'd like to stack to plots and expects nice cumulative plot as well.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(time, value, group = name)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = name), position = "stack")
```

However things get completely messed up:

[stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypXe8.png)

Can anyone spot the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are duplicated observations - on the first graph these are plotted on top of each other so you don't notice but when stacked these values are summed and the results are the spikes in your second graph. Not sure of your expected outcome but you may want to deduplicate before plotting.

Comment: Yes! That's it @H1. Could you please post it as an answer? Thank you!